# Strip Tags from Query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, strip-tags

I have heard it is bad to allow data entry via an HTML form without first stripping out the tags, so I have come here for help to see if there are ways around this.

I have a query to update records in the database, but I want to strip out the tags first. The query is below. Please if there are any suggestions to do this via PHP

```
  $res = "UPDATE events SET event_type ='$_POST[event_type]', 
  title = '$_POST[title]', description ='$_POST[description]', 
  location ='$_POST[location]', image ='', image_name ='', 
  address_1='$_POST[address_1]', address_2='$_POST[address_2]', 
  city='$_POST[city]', Postcode='$_POST[Postcode]', country='$_POST[country]', 
  available_ticketqty='$_POST[available_ticketqty]'  WHERE event_id= $_POST[id]";
```

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/de/function.strip-tags.php - maybe 5 seconds fo google ("Php strip tags")

Comment: You heard wrong. What's more dangerous is Little Bobby Tables.

Comment: (for those not familiar with little bobby: https://xkcd.com/327/ )

Comment: Take a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) for info on SQL Injection

Comment: If you are talking about SQL Injection protection, then PHP has some functions for you - stripslashes(), mysql_real_escape_string()

Comment: google: php strip tags

Comment: @Naman Or one can just use prepared statements instead of functions that are part of deprecated interfaces (`mysql_*`).

Comment: Have a read of [Security Best Practices - Unfiltered Input, Unescaped Output](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/security/best-practices#Unfiltered_Input_Unescaped_Output) and [Why escape-on-input is a bad idea](http://lukeplant.me.uk/blog/posts/why-escape-on-input-is-a-bad-idea/)

Answer (score -1):

The safest way for you to accomplish what you want is to use PDO and prepared statements. Prepared statements will ensure that your data is properly escaped.

```
<?php
// configuration
$dbtype    = "sqlite";
$dbhost    = "localhost";
$dbname    = "test";
$dbuser    = "root";
$dbpass    = "admin";

// database connection
$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$dbhost;dbname=$dbname",$dbuser,$dbpass);

// new data
$title = 'PHP Pattern';
$author = 'Imanda';
$id = 3;
// query
$sql = "UPDATE books 
        SET title=?, author=?
        WHERE id=?";
$q = $conn->prepare($sql);
$q->execute(array($title,$author,$id));    

?>
```

Comment: Please add some links to the reference of PDO, along with the example.